# redirect based on referrer domain in blogger blog using javascript redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, dns, blogspot

I have 3 blogger blog with domain looks like

```
example1.blogspot.com 
example2.blogspot.com 
example3.blogspot.com
```

If someone clicks any of the links below from a particular site (example, google.com) they should not face any redirect but when they access the link from anywhere in the web they should be redirected to example.com/alllinks . There wont be a single permalink match between 3 blogs.

```
example1.blogspot.com 
example2.blogspot.com 
example3.blogspot.com
example1.blogspot.com/alllinks1 
example2.blogspot.com/alllinks2 
example3.blogspot.com/alllinks3
```

For Example,,,
user from anywhere except google.com

```
example1.blogspot.com to example.com/page1
example2.blogspot.com to example.com/page2
example3.blogspot.com to example.com/page3
example1.blogspot.com/alllinks1 to example.com/alllinks1
example2.blogspot.com/alllinks2 to example.com/alllinks2
example3.blogspot.com/alllinks3 to example.com/alllinks3
```

user referred from google.com

```
example1.blogspot.com (noredirect)
example2.blogspot.com (noredirect)
example3.blogspot.com (noredirect)
example1.blogspot.com/alllinks1 (noredirect)
example2.blogspot.com/alllinks2 (noredirect)
example3.blogspot.com/alllinks3 (noredirect)
```

Since the blogs are blogspot blog i dont have access to .htaccess and have no option like wordpress plugins. So is it possible to achieve the above in blogger blog? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I never had to deal with blogspot, but I guess you can do server-side scripting, right?

Comment: Forget about that. Just do `var ref=document.referrer`

Comment: @Psioniax thanks for the reply... can you please explain what i have do.. I dont know what doing var ref=document.referrer means

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the referrer in Javscript. After that you can redirect your users based on it. (To test it, try copying the link to this answer, go to [google](http://www.google.com) and then paste the link you copied in your ADDRESS bar)

```js
var ref=document.referrer;
document.getElementById("ref").innerHTML += ref + "<br />";
if (ref.indexOf("google") > -1)
  {
    document.getElementById("ref").innerHTML += ("You came here from google");
  }
```

```html
<div id="ref"></div>
```